# Display an array data from two tables in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

I've two tables on my database, monitor `[pk = idMonitor]` and monitor_data `[pk = idMonitor_data]`.

[Please click you can see the tables fields here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSLoh.png). As you can see i put the array data in table monitor_data.

I want to Update the condition for every idinventory `where monitor_data.idMonitor = $id`.

But first i want to display the current data of 'monitordate','idinventory', and 'condition' from database to my view.

**My controller**

```
public function edit($id=0) {
     $dataa = $this->monitor_m->get_record(array('monitor_data.idMonitor'=>$id),true);


     $this->data->monitordate = $dataa->monitordate;
     $this->data->condition = $dataa->condition; <-line 20

     $this->data->detail = $this->monitor_m->get_record(array('monitor_data.idMonitor'=>$id),true);

     $this->template->set_title('SMIB | Monitoring')
     ->render('monitor_edit',$this->data);  
}
```

**My View (monitor_edit)**

```
<?php echo form_open(site_url("monitor/ubah"),'data-ajax="false"'); ?>
        <?php foreach ($detail as $items): ?>   
            <h4><?php echo '[ '.$items['idinventory'].' ] '?> </h4>
            <?php echo form_label ('Condition   : ');
                  echo form_dropdown('condition', array('good'=>'Good','broke'=>'Broken','lost'=>'Lost'),@$items['condition']); 
         ?>         
        <?php endforeach; ?>
       <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

**My Model**

```
class Monitor_m extends MY_Model {

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        parent::set_table('monitor','idMonitor');
    }

public function get_record($id = 0,$get_user = FALSE) {
        $this->db->where($id);
        if ($get_user){
            $this->db->join('monitor_data','monitor_data.idMonitor = monitor.idMonitor');
            $this->db->join('inventory','inventory.idinventory = monitor_data.idinventory');           
            $this->db->join('user','user.id_user = monitor.id_user');

        }
         $data = parent::get_array();

        return $this->improve_data($data);

   }
```

Here is my problem : its work fine for *monitordate* code in my controller, BUT i keep getting an error for *condition* code 
Maybe because i use `'monitor_data.idMonitor'` as my parameter `$id` not idinventory. how can i use 2 parameters for example like `where idMonitor=$id and idinventory=$idiventory`.

Do i explain it right ?

> Severity: Notice   Message:  Trying to get property of non-object
>   Filename: controllers/monitor.php   Line Number: 20

Please Please help me, i dont know what is wrong with my controller :( i've searching the solution but none of those work. :(

Comment: The condition field is in the monitor_data table, not in the monitor one.

Comment: On a side not follow this way for file naming and class naming http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

Comment: @Shadow yes, that's why i use get_record function in my model. i add my model code above.

Answer (score 0):

It's weird if you can get monitordate but can't get condition.

Can you edit your controller to be like this?

```
public function get_record($id = 0,$get_user = FALSE) {
        $this->db->where($id);
        if ($get_user){
            $this->db->join('monitor_data','monitor_data.idMonitor = monitor.idMonitor');
            $this->db->join('inventory','inventory.idinventory = monitor_data.idinventory');           
            $this->db->join('user','user.id_user = monitor.id_user');

        }
       //  $data = parent::get_array();
           $data = $this->db->result_array(); 
           print_r($data);
           echo $this->db->last_query();
           exit;

        return $this->improve_data($data);

   }
```